# journal to submit mathematic books' review

Tags: journals, peer-review

it has been asked to me to write a review on a book about the history of mathematics in Italy between the two world wars. 
The book is a non-technical one. I would like to know which journal accepts these kind of book review. 
From my google search seems to me that the Bulletin of the AMS accept only technical book review. So here I am, asking for some journal's suggestion where to publish this review.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: *Mathematical Intelligencer* might be a good fit.

Comment: The German "Mathematische Semesterberichte" publishes such reviews (probably only in German).

Comment: It seems that a similar question has been asked before at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/154084/18398

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [BSHM Bulletin: Journal of the British Society for the History of Mathematics](http://www.tandfonline.com/loi/tbsh20#.VJQijcFow) and [Historia Mathematica](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/historia-mathematica/).

Comment: It seems that these two are the top journals in history of mathematics.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:History_of_mathematics_journals)