# Which journals publish mathematics book reviews?

Tags: big-list, journals, peer-review

Which mathematics journals publish book reviews? So far I have the following:

1. Notices of the American Mathematical Society
2. Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society (From looking at its [website](https://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/aboutbull) it seems the book reviews it publishes have to be invited)
3. American Mathematical Monthly
4. [MAA Reviews](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews) (an online resource - but it qualifies for my purpose)
5. The Mathematical Intelligencer (?) - seems to publish reviews, but does not explicitly say so in its ["aims and scope"](https://www.springer.com/journal/283/aims-and-scope)
6. [The Mathematics Student](http://www.indianmathsociety.org.in/ms.htm)
7. [The Gazette of the Australian Math Society](https://austms.org.au/publications/gazette/)
8. [British Journal for the History of Mathematics](https://www.tandfonline.com/toc/tbsh21/36/1) (related to history of mathematics only)
9. [Historia Mathematica](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/historia-mathematica/) (related to  history of mathematics only)

What else?

The answers to the question ["journal to submit mathematic books' review,"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191113/journal-to-submit-mathematic-books-review) which was really only about history of mathematics, have been incorporated in the above list.

I tried to go through the answers to the question ["Which journals publish expository work?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work) - but most of them do not seem to publish book reviews.

**Context:** A book of mine has been accepted for publication (by a well-known publisher on mathematics). As part of the final submission I have been asked this:

> Please list, in order of importance, all journals you believe might review your book. This should include both U.S. and non-U.S. journals. (Please remember that not all journals accept book reviews.)

(I do have a proper MathOverflow account, decided to post this anonymously in order to avoid self-promotion.)

Comment: 1) SIAM Review (a publication of the Society for Ind. and App. Math.) 2) CMS Notes (a publication of the Canadian Math. Soc.)

Comment: You'd think the publisher would already be familiar with the well-known journals.  So you might want to focus on those with a particular niche that your book would fit, e.g. decent journals in your subfield.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Decent niche journals in mathematics usually do not publish book reviews.